# How to use TreeView.AfterSelect and TreeView.DrawNode methods?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have `MyForm.cs, MyForm.Designer.cs` files in my project, in `MyForm.Designer.cs` I did like this:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TreeView myTreeView;
this.myTreeView = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();
.........
this.myTreeView.AfterSelect += 
                           new TreeViewEventHandler(this.myTreeView_AfterSelect);
```

in `MyForm.cs` like this:

```
private void myTreeView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
          //........;
        }
```

also I have `CostumeTreeView` class in other files(`CostumeTreeView.cs` and `CostumeTreeView.Designer.cs`), in 
`CostumeTreeView.Designer.cs` I did like this:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TreeView myCostumeTreeView
this.myCostumeTreeView = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();
...........
this.myCostumeTreeView.DrawMode = 
                          System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawAll;
this.myCostumeTreeView.DrawNode += 
               new DrawTreeNodeEventHandler(this.myCostumeTreeView_DrawNode);
```

in `CostumeTreeView.cs` :

```
private void myCostumeTreeView_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {
        ........
            //Here is the problem, myTreeView isn't seen here
            e.Node.Tag = myTreeView.SelectedNode.Text; 
        }
```

I need when `myTreeView`'s node is selected, all tags in `myCostumeTreeView` is been changed using after select function
(all methods are in one namespace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your TreeView controls are on different forms, they either need to reference each other through a form property or an event so that the controls can talk to each other.

The other thing I see is that you probably shouldn't be setting a property in a draw or paint event, which you are doing with `e.Node.Tag = myTreeView.SelectedNode.Text;` in the DrawNode event.  The only thing you should be doing in the DrawNode event is drawing the node, very little else.

To make the reference, your costume form needs a variable and just pass it through the constructor, something like:

```
private MyForm mainForm;

private CostumeTreeView(MyForm mf) {
  InitializeComponents();
  mainForm = mf;
}
```

Now you can reference the TreeView control:

```
private void myCostumeTreeView_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e) {
  ........
  e.Node.Tag = mainForm.myTreeView.SelectedNode.Text; 
}
```

Again, using the DrawNode event to set the tag of the nodes isn't necessary.  You are creating a dependency on your GUI, which will make maintenance and debugging difficult in the future.

Comment: `e.Node.Tag = myTreeView.SelectedNode.Text` -only part of DrawNode method, I really need this because I'm totally changing drawing

Comment: `TreeView` and `CostumeTreeView` are on different forms, how can I use an event ? Could you give me an example please? How can I return `myTreeView.SelectedNode.Text` from one control to another (from `TreeView` to `CostumeTreeView`)

Comment: @Steven Updated example of how to pass a reference from the parent form to the other form.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to acces to the Treeview property present in TreeNode class.

```
    e.Node.Tag = e.Node.TreeView.SelectedNode.Text;
```

You should have acces to it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a coordinator class and pass both trees to the coordinator. Have the coordinator subscribe to after select of one tree and on after select, do what it is supposed to in the other tree.

You don't need to owner draw it all unless I'm missing something.